# How to command line compile a Visual Studio project using msbuild and setting C++17?

Tags: c++, msbuild, c++17

I've made a build.xml file to use within my VS project,  but it requires to be compiled using /std:c++17 and I don't know how to set it into the build configuration xml.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
        <SourceFolder>.\</SourceFolder>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="Start">
        <CallTarget Targets="Build"></CallTarget>
    </Target>
    <Target Name = "Build">
        <MSBuild 
            Projects=".\FknUtils.sln"
            Properties="Configuration=Release"
            Targets="Clean;Build"
            ContinueOnError="false"
            StopOnFirstFailure="true"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by right clicking on the project in the `solution explorer`, selecting `Properties`, and in the `General` separator, in the `C++ Language Standard` field select `ISO C++17 Standard (std:c++17)`.

This will add to your configurations file the option `<LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>`.

Something like:

```html
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>
      </PrecompiledHeader>
      <WarningLevel>TurnOffAllWarnings</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>

      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard> 

      <TreatWarningAsError>false</TreatWarningAsError>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Comment: Well, actually your suggestion indeed sets the Language Standard to stdcpp17, but when I call msbuild in the command line it still complains the compiler is not set to C++17.

Comment: If your using command line compilation you must add `/std:c++17`

Comment: I tried "MSBuild.exe /p:useenv=true /std:c++17" but it does not accept /std:c++17

Comment: @JoaoBarros Oh I see, I was talking about `cl.exe`, for `MSBuild.exe` I'm not sure, I'll take a look.

Comment: @JoaoBarros, I can't reproduce you problem, I used comma separated `using`s in the project which is a feature only availabe after C++17, I changed the languange standard like explained in the answer, and it compiled fine with no warnings and no errors. Just to be sure I configured it back to C++14 and sure enough it did complain.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you run it the IDE does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work fine in the IDE. 
I didn't get your statement "I used comma separated usings in the project..."

Comment: Got it! I had multiple platforms configured on my project, but I had the setting into x86, so I had to force using it:  "MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform=x86". Now it works! Thanks Anastaciu for your help!

Comment: @JoaoBarros, the comma separated usings is for example `using std::string, std::cout;` before C++17 this was not possible, so I added it to test if the compiler was indeed using C++17 standard, anyway, I'm glad you solved the issue. Beautiful family BTW :)