# How do I set the C++ Language standard in msbuild from the comand line

Tags: c++, msbuild, c++17

I am using msbuild to build a c++ project. The project requires C++17 (or higher). I use the following command:
`& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe' .\Tutorials.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`

How do I pass the language standard to the command? I know how to change this in visual studio, however I need to do this non-interactively because the command will be run in a continuos integration context.

Comment: The version would be set in the vcxproj file; not via command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to command line compile a Visual Studio project using msbuild and setting C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785887/how-to-command-line-compile-a-visual-studio-project-using-msbuild-and-setting-c)

Comment: sadly no. This requires manual editing of the project file. I wan't to set the language standard non-interactively. The /std:c++17 flag is not recognised by msbuild

Comment: You can try `-property:LanguageStandard=stdcpp17`

Comment: The linked question in the comment from @JaMiT shows that `<LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>` is added as metadata on the `ClCompile` item collection. It is not a property. Instead you probably need to look for a property that is mapped to the `AdditionalOptions` parameter of the [CL task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/cl-task?view=vs-2022) and append the [`/std` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170).